# adding data to a confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I have this dialog function in which it asks "add(the inputted amoun)?"

In my code i used this `("Add " + amntDATA + " ?")`. but this is the outcome

> Add [object HTMLInputElement] ?

html code:

```
 Amount: <input type="text" name="contriamnt" id="contriamnt" size="15" placeholder=" Amount"></br></br>
 <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">ADD</button></br>
```

script:

```
 function ConfirmFunction() {
        var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt; 
        if (confirm("Add " + amntDATA + " ?") == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `amntDATA` contains a reference to the input element, not its `value`...

Comment: OffTopic: self closing tags have the `/` at the end, not the start. So it should be `<br/>` not `</br>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use java script property `.value`
e.g. amntDATA.value;

```
function ConfirmFunction() {
    var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt; 
    if (confirm("Add " + amntDATA.value + " ?") == true) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
}
```

For further reference or knowledge go through this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp).

Answer (score 1):

amntDATA is just an input element. You need to get the **value** of the amntDATA element, get it like:

```
function ConfirmFunction() {
        var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt; 
        if (confirm("Add " + amntDATA.value + " ?") == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}
```